# python pdb: step into a function called from console

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb, spyder

Note: To explain this quickly I'm going to talk about this from the perspective of working in Spyder.

If the a function is called in my code, I can put a break point next to where it's called and then when my code gets to that point I can click the "Step into function.." button to see what happens inside this function.

Suppose I'm at some arbitrary breakpoint and want to see what happens inside a function that's not in my code.  Is there any way to call this function through the pdb console and "step into" said function call?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ipdb`. put `ipdb.set_trace()` wherever you want to debug. Then press `s` to step into the function.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried function decorators? (maybe read about it)

```
def foo():
    print 'Hello pdb'

def add_breakpoint(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        pdb.set_trace()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper

foo = add_breakpoint(foo)
```

This will add some calls in your debug, but it will get the job done.
hoping to hear if worked!

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason the above solution didn't work for me.  When pdb is already sitting at a breakpoint, any functions called ignore breakpoints an execute normally.

Comment: Instead of leaving the answer stranded, like the statements 'maybe read about it', you could provide some useful links you referred that help the cause.